# Using slider on combined bar and linechart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization

I successfully build a chart combining bar-chart and line-chart in d3.js and added a slider to it that updates the x-axis but not the chart itself. All my attempts failed so far. I found a very nice example which is kind of similar: http://bl.ocks.org/dem42/3878029

I made a fiddle, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/karolinka/zpy0pqLu/10/
Thanks for thinking about it in advance.
This is the code within the slider function:

```
        x.domain(d3.range(minv, maxv + 1));
        xAxis.tickFormat(function(i) {
            return times[i];
        });
        svg.transition().duration(750)
            .select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);

        lineScaleX.domain(d3.range(minv, maxv + 1));
        svg.transition().duration(750)
            .select(".lines").attr("d", line);
```

Comment: I know what the problem is now, just have to find a way to fix it. The charts have an ordinal scale but he slider ui-values are returning numbers that I have to convert to strings again.

Comment: Update: it´s getting better but there´s still bars from the old domain: http://jsfiddle.net/karolinka/zpy0pqLu/28/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyones interested: the line interpolation is not nice, but it works now: http://jsfiddle.net/karolinka/zpy0pqLu/40/. In the end I hid the additional elements with JQuery
like this:

```
if(newtimes.length<5){
   $(".bars:nth-child(5)").hide();
} else {
    $(".bars:nth-child(5)").show();
}``
```

Not the best way I guess but if I remove old elements and then append them again, I´m not getting a smooth transition.